# How do I determine class of object at mouse position (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouseover

I have a class ("foo" say) in my 2D project, and when I obtain a reference to a game object at my mouse position I want to determine whether the object is of the foo class. I obtain the object with

```
GameObject objAtMouse = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos), Vector2.zero).transform.gameObject;
```

where mousePos is the position of my mouse, and it seems to be working as intended. To test for class I have tried the following:

1. if(objAtMouse is foo){...}
2. foo fooAtMouse = objAtMouse as foo;
   if(fooAtMouse){...}
3. if ((objAtMouse.GetComponent("foo") as foo) != null){...}

Option 1. was suggested [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/check-the-class-of-an-object.24715/) and is the only one which does not produce an error, but yields the warning

> The given expression is never of the provided ('foo') type

Option 2., also suggested at the link above, yields the error

> Cannot convert type 'UnityEngineGameObject' to 'foo' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Option 3. was suggested [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/check-if-a-gameobject-has-a-certain-script.88484/) and produces the error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

This seems like a simple task, but I'm having a bit of trouble with this one. So, how can I determine the class/type of the object that my mouse is over?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Foo` is a component, which it probably is since you attached it to a `GameObject`, then option 3 is pretty close. But you don't need to cast it `as Foo`.

```
Foo fooComponent = objAtMouse.GetComponent<Foo>();

if (fooComponent == null) .. //no Foo component.
```

Note that you should check if `objAtMouse` is `null` first..

Comment: Thanks for this reply :) I've tried your suggestion, but I get the NullReferenceException listed above. Am I missing something?

Comment: Which line does the `NullReferenceException` occur? Did u check if `objAtMouse` is `null`?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I check first if objAtMouse is null, and only within the resulting if block do the subsequent test on fooComponent. The error occurs at runtime; is there a way to get more detail about which line causes the error? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, when unity console shows the NullReferenceException error message, you can click on it to show details like which script and which line it occurred at. If you are using monodevelop editor, double click the error and it will bring you to the line of code

Comment: Thanks very much for that tip! So I did this, and it looks like the line is the one above GameObject objAtMouse = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos), Vector2.zero).transform.gameObject;  but this was working before. Any ideas?

Comment: Your raycast, are you sure it hit some valid collider? Seems like you can be accessing the transform of a null ref returned by raycast

Comment: "the line is the line above GameObject objAtMouse = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos)" so it is not a line related to the post since we don't see it.

Comment: @Everts that code is the first line of code in my post

Answer (score 1):

First off, that first line cannot work out as it is:

```
GameObject objAtMouse = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos), Vector2.zero).transform.gameObject;
```

This assumes you have a constant successful hit.

```
Raycast2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos), Vector2.zero);
if(hit.transform != null)
{
     GameObject objAtMouse = hit.transform.gameObject;
     if(objAtMouse.GetComponent<Foo>() != null){
          // Object has component Foo on it
     }
}
```

Another solution would be to have Foo type telling about itself:

```
public class Foo:MonoBehaviour{
     private static HashSet<Transform>fooCollection;
     private void Awake()
     {
          if(fooCollection  == null)
          {
              fooCollection = new HashSet<Transform>(); 
          }
          fooCollection.Add(this.transform);
     }

     private void OnDestroy()
     {
          fooCollection.Remove(this.transform);
     }

     public static bool CompareFooObject(Transform tr)
     {
          if(tr == null) return false;
          return fooCollection.Contains(tr);
     }
}
```

then you can use it as:

```
Raycast2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos), Vector2.zero);
if(Foo.CompareFooObject(hit.transform))
{
    // Is Foo type
}
```

The advantage of HashSet is that it is fairly fast to find item. You could also extend the usage of the pattern so it can be used with any type with generic, but I guess this is enough for now.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, +1. I accepted @Lincoln's answer as the check for nullity (which you also mention) turned out to be the key, though there were other kinks that I had to work out, and he answered earlier. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

All object in the scene is gameobject itself and won't be cild class. Other class you want to find would be component

So you must use `obj.GetComponents` to get it out of gameobject

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign it a tag and then use

```
objAtmouse.compareTag('your tag name');
```